# Python Dictionary example

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

I am new to python and need help to understand this piece of code used to create a dictionary

```
new_key_lis = [18,23,45]
b= dict([(23,18)])

c = dict(zip(new_key_lis, [None]*len(new_key_lis)))
print(c)
```

I would like to know about the difference between  [None] and None ?

Comment: The same as the difference between `[1]` and `1`.

Comment: An array with one entry vs a single value? But you are probably more interested in how the '*' operator works here if I had to guess.

Comment: FWIW, this could be much more simply expressed as `c = {k: None for k in new_key_list}`.  Or  `c = dict.fromkeys(new_key_lis, None)`.  Building a list of values to zip with the list of keys is a very roundabout/confusing way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

`None` is the special value for nothing, the sole value of the `NoneType` type.

`[None]` is a list that contains exactly one value, and that value is `None`.

So not only `None` and `[None]` and different, but they have different type.

To go one step further, a list can be multiplied with an integer to repeat its elements. For example `[1, 2] * 3` is `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`